# Can a file run with an executable on windows that modifies a config file used by the executable?

Tags: xml, dll, steam

I was thinking about creating a mod for a game that randomizes lines of code on startup of the game. Specifically I thought of modding Forza Horizon 4 to randomize lines from a point "a" to point "b", then from a point "c" to a point "d" and so on to truly randomize the radio from the game. I think this is a .dll I am thinking about, but I don't have any knowledge of coding and so I don't know how to create it or if it is even possible to have a file modifying a config file that is in use by the game. I tried already modifying the config while the game is running, the game doesn't bother with that, but I haven't come any further. The config is written in an .xml file. The reason why I want this is because the game itself doesn't randomize and if you mod the radio to have a lot more songs, these extra songs are played rarely and only take up space. By randomizing these lines on startup this problem would be solved. The .xml file looks like this:

```
      <PlayList Type="FreeRoam">
        <Entry Name="<Gametitle>_<Radioname>_<artist>_<songtitle>" />
...
        <Entry Name="<Gametitle>_<Radioname>_<artist>_<songtitle>" />
      </PlayList>
      <PlayList Type="Event">
        <Entry Name="<Gametitle>_<Radioname>_<artist>_<songtitle>" />
...
        <Entry Name="<Gametitle>_<Radioname>_<artist>_<songtitle>" />
      </PlayList>
```

Everything between these `<PlayList Type="FreeRoam">` and `</PlayList>` should be randomized.

At this point I'm manually randomizing these lines with Notepad++ by selecting the lines that should be randomized and then use "Edit>Line Operations>Randomize Line Order", but as you can probably expect, this is extremely painful if you want to do this regularly, so that's why I wanted to have that.

Comment: Windows does not allow any application to modify a file that is already opened by another application.  When a second application attempts to open the file it gets only read permission and not write permission.

Comment: I already used an application to modify the file while the game was running, so this probably isn't an issue.

Comment: Once game is running the app doesn't have the config file open and uses config at time app was opened.  The changes to config will not take place until app is opened again.

Comment: yeah that's okay for me

Comment: I need to see the parent of playlist to randomize the list.  Very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort the playlist using PowerShell.  I made the parent of PlayList PlayLists.  Here is code

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$playlists = $xDoc.Descendants("Playlists")
$rand = [System.Random]::new()
$entries = $playlists.Descendants("Entry")

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($entry in $entries)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue $rand.Next()
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName XElement -NotePropertyValue $entry

   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table
$table = $table | Sort-Object -Property Name
$table
$playlists.RemoveNodes()
$newPlayList =[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get("PlayList"))
$newPlayList.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new("Type", "Random"));
$playlists.Add($newPlayList);
foreach($row in $table)
{
   $newPlayList.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XElement]$row.XElement);
}
$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```